# Set Next Request Not Working In Postman Collection Runner

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I'm running on Windows 10 with the latest version, 7.21.1. I imported the example collection featured in their documentation - https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/collection-runs/building-workflows/. I run Request 1 in the collection through the Runner and Request 4 does not trigger as it seems it should. It is setup in Tests and seems correct based on their documentation. I have my own collection I was trying this with, but when it was not working I then tried this sample and realized there was something else amiss.

Any assistance would be helpful! I can provide more information if needed.

This is what the example collection has in Request 1 under Tests: `postman.setNextRequest('Request 4');`

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the actual flow or script that you're using this in please - That line on its own is meaningless :)

Comment: I was using the example Postman provided, which was just that. Here is the actual collection you can import. I just imported this to test.

https://assets.postman.com/postman-docs/58793802.json

Comment: I just imported and ran the collection, request 1 and Request 4 ran.

Comment: What's your environment? Are you using a paid version of postman or the free versions? I am evaluating this for use to automate testing of our web services.

Comment: I got the sample running. I assumed I only had to check the initial request not all of them. I will keep working on my collection to see if it will work.

Comment: Thanks! I understand this more after running it a few times and managing the order of requests.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. I didn't understand the flow of how the operation worked or the flow of runner. All requests that could be called next need to be selected in runner. And this operation works like a goto where all requests after the request that is run next all run. Closing this out.